# Powershell: i cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell

WHen i run this script, i keep getting an error for Tostring()

```
$path = "C:\Users\amoso\Desktop\Applications"
$Applications = import-csv "C:\Users\amoso\Desktop\Applications\pkgs.csv" -Delimiter "," -Header 'Installer', 'Switch' | Select-Object Installler, Switch

foreach ($Application in $Applications) {

    $Appexec = $Application.Installer
    $Appexec = $Appexec.Tostring()

    $pkgs = Get-ChildItem $path$Appexec | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $Appexec }  

    foreach ($pkg in $pkgs) {
        
        $switch = $Application.Switch
        $switch = $switch.Tostring()

        mkdir c:\Temp\Applications -Force
        Copy-Item "$path$Appexec" -Recurse c:\Temp\Applications -Force
        Write-Host "Installing $Appexec silently, please wait..." -foregroundColor Yellow
        Start-Process "c:\Temp\Applications\$Appexec" -ArgumentList "switch" -Wait

        Remove-Item "c:\Temp\Applications\$Appexec" -Recurse -Force
        Write-Host "Installation of $Appexec completed" -foregroundColor Green
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:7 char:5
+     $Appexec =$Appexec.Tostring()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

With the first foreach loop i get an error for Tostring()
But with the second foreach loop i dont get any error.

I dont know where i made a mistake.

Comment: The implication is that `$Application` has no `.Installer` property (CSV column) so that `$Application.Installer` yields `$null`, so the subsequent `.ToString()` call fails. As an aside: Properties on objects parsed from CSV are _always_ `[string]`-typed, so there's no need to call `.ToString()`